# New object every time I call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this function to create an object:

```
function Building(owner, type, hp) {
this.owner = owner;
this.type = type;
this.hp = hp;
}
```

So, every time I call it, a new object is created.

```
var barracks = new Building(player,bBarracks,"100");
```

But I have an another function which can be called several times.

```
function build() {
if (building == 1) {

    $("."+xPos+"-"+yPos).addClass("building-powerplant").addClass("taken");
    hudBuildings("powerPlant"); initialize();
    hudBuildings("barracks");
    ...
} ... }
```

I want to create a new object every time build() is called and give it a name of "id"+[increased number], ex. id1, id2, ..., id10.
So every time I call function, an object is created. I tried increasing a number by 1 every time it is used, but I can't figure it out how to write it in. Honestly, that was kinda dumb:

```
objID++;
var id+(objID) = new Building(player,bPowPlant,"100");
```

Any ideas how to figure this out? :)

Comment: How about `var buildings = {}; ... buildings[id + objID] = new Building(...); `

Comment: What will you need this id for? Because a simple array seems sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you keep the objects in an array? that way the "key" automatically sort of becomes the incremementing ID.

so you have earlier on:

`var objects = [];`

Then in the build function you do like

`objects.push(new Building(player,bPowPlant,"100"))`

Then in the objects variables you will have all of the objects you have created. Accessible by objects[0], objects[1] etc.

Comment: It worked. You saved my project and now I understood arrays! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to save a string as a variable name, you'll need to save it as an object key. You could build your own object, although a common method is to save to the window object using `window[variableName]`. As for the id number, you can save that to a higher scoped variable and then increment inside the `build()` function.

```
var objId = 0;

function build() {
    if (building == 1) {

    $("."+xPos+"-"+yPos).addClass("building-powerplant").addClass("taken");
    hudBuildings("powerPlant"); initialize();
    hudBuildings("barracks");

    objId++;
    ...
} ... }
```

Then when you create a new object:

```
window["id"+objId] = new Building(player,bPowPlant,"100");
```